# Read-Host verification using a files contents

Tags: powershell, input, match, verification

I'm trying to carry out a `read-host` command that only accepts an input where this matches a hostname listed in a text file. Below is my code I'm using, can anyone help?

It is trying to match the whole text file and not just any line of it, which doesn't need to be casesenstivie at all:

```
$Input = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\username\Computer-Results.txt"
Do { 
    Try { 
            $HostnameOK = $True
            $HostnameEntry = Read-Host "Enter something"}
            Catch { $HostnameOK = $False
             Write-Host "This is the catch."}
           }

    Until (($HostnameEntry -contains $Input))


$Input
```

Comment: You have the condition backwards `$Input -contains $HostnameEntry`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the condition backwards.

```
Until (($HostnameEntry -contains $Input))
```

Should be

```
Until ($fileInput -contains $HostnameEntry)
```

If you have at least PowerShell 3.0 the `-in` operator is a little more intuitive

```
Until ($HostnameEntry -in $fileInput)
```

As other answers and comments point out you are using an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx). Change the variable name.

> `$Input`:
>          Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a
>          function. The $input variable is available only to functions and script
>          blocks (which are unnamed functions).  In the Process block of a
>          function, the $input variable enumerates the object that is currently
>          in the pipeline. When the Process block  completes, there are no objects
>          left in the pipeline, so the $input variable enumerates an empty
>          collection. If the function does not have a Process block, then in the
>          End block, the $input variable enumerates the collection of all input to
>          the function.

Comment: Also `$Input` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) and shouldn't be used here.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `$Input` is a default PowerShell variable. You should use another variable to add the contents of the file. Something like:

```
$fileinput = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\username\Computer-Results.txt"
do {
    $HostnameEntry = Read-Host "Enter Something"
} until ($fileinput -contains $HostnameEntry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Computer-Results.txt'

do {
    $HostnameEntry = Read-Host 'Enter something'
    if ($Computers -notcontains $HostnameEntry)
    {
        Write-Host "Sorry, [$($HostnameEntry)] isn't acceptable"
        pause
    }
} while ($Computers -contains $HostnameEntry)
```

Comment: You should add some description as to what is different here and how it works. As of now this _could_ be flagged.

Comment: Flagged for what? Being too helpful? I figured this was so close to what he was doing it was obvious.

Comment: Obvious for you and me sure. But maybe not to the OP or the rest of the community. Code only answer are discouraged. That is all. No need for sarcasm. I think if the answer was obvious the OP would not have asked.

Comment: The sarcasm was only stemmed from the fact that you mentioned the reply being flagged. Seemed like a threat to me. Here's a more PC way to put your reply: "You might want to add some description to your code.  That looks good but the OP might not understand it as is".

Comment: I get you understanding. That is the text I use in this case most of the time. It's just text so it can be easily misinterpreted and body language is hard to convey. By the strict definition I was not threatening. Can't please everyone unfortunately. Either way I hope you got my point. Happy Stacking.